# How to draw Annotation, on constant range from screen?

Tags: 3d-view, grease-pencil, annotation

I also tried doing such with Grease Pencil, with no luck .

When its wanted to paint a 3D scheme with no need of precise range between entities, such way of the depth selection is much more ergonomic .

Comment: could you please be more precise? All the annotation options are on the top of the 3D view, Placement > View, 3D Cursor or Surface, maybe you're looking for View?

Comment: @moonboots the Placement -- View, attaches the output to the screen . I mean painting 3D entities .

Comment: an annotation in 3D that would keep its size no matter the zoom?

Comment: @moonboots
 "draw (:) Annotation on constant range",
 "draw Annotation, on constant range",
 "draw Annotation from constant range" . 
you are right, sor

Comment: Please add a diagram of what you would want to do and how you want it to behave

Comment: i fixed the syntax mistake in the title .

Comment: Annotation or grease pencil? Those are two different tools. Also please explain clearly what you want.

Comment: @susu there is a "also" word written . when you LMB-Drag in 3D viewport, the drawing is added perpendicularly and on defined/default range from the camera .